# How to debug safe-area-inset-top etc. using chrome/firefox dev tools

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

When designing for newer iPhones/devices with a notch, I use safe-area-inset-* a lot. I would like to preview what my layout is going to look like on my pc though, because it's sometimes not possible to use a native device. Is there an option in firefox/chrome devtools, so that I don't have to go through deploying to staging every time?